# Get the link for a route - Asp.net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I want to get just the link to a route. Using Html.ActionLink and Html.RouteLink returns the link in an anchor tag. Is there any way in which I can get only the link.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use [Url.Action](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.urlhelper.action.aspx) and [Url.RouteUrl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.urlhelper.routeurl.aspx) methods.